# Append HTML tag to Class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add an `<ul></ul>` tag instead a class `<div class='box'></div>` I use appendTo() in this way

`$('<ul>').appendTo('.box');`

But I get:

`<div class="box"><li>You did not enter your first name</li><ul></ul></div>`

And of couse should i get:

`<div class="box"><ul><li>You did not enter your first name</li></ul></div>`

Comment: Where's the `li` coming from, can you post whatever code you've got that creates/appends it?

Answer (score 2):

If the `li` is already in the `div` (which would be invalid html):

```
$('.box li').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
```

Should work.

If the `li` is added after the `ul` is appended:

```
$('<li />').text('whatever').appendTo('.box ul');
```

The fact that you're using `append()` suggests that the `li` is already present though, which seems a little odd.

API references:

- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/),
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/), explaining why append inserts the `ul` *after* the `li`, which seemed to surprise you.

Comment: @David Thomas It works. But I get an error (with W3C) and I don't see the <ul></ul> tag when I check the source (but I see it with firebug)

Comment: @Mini: what error are you getting with the W3C? And yes: the html source *won't change in response to DOM manipulation*, since the source is the `html` file that's resident on the server; whereas Firebug will reflect the DOM that Firefox is manipulating/working with.

Comment: @David Thomas `document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul"` there is another solution to added a real </ul></ul> with jQuery :D

Comment: @Mini: the error you're getting is because `li` **is not a valid child of any element other than `ul` or `ol`**. Note the first parenthesis in my answer. If the `li` is in the static html file, you should probably add the `ul` (or `ol`) to the static html file too.

Comment: @David Thomas: I can't added it because the HTML code is a sentence like `{$errormessage}`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mini: you're absolutely welcome =) Could you add into your question where the html is generated (probably something like `var htmlString = '<div class="box">...</div>';`) and how it's added to the page?

Answer (score 0):

`appendTo` will simply add the element at the bottom of your container, as in the code you've posted. What you want appears to be something more like

```
$('.box li').wrap('<ul/>');
```

Comment: This will result in <div class="box"><ul><li/></ul><ul><li /></ul></div>, won't it?

Comment: if there's more than one `li`, then yes, `wrapAll` would be preferable.

Comment: Not necessarily at the 'bottom,' (though I understand your meaning) it will insert the element as the **last-child** of the element it's `append()`-ed to though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
$('.box>li').wrapAll('<ul/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
$('.box').wrapInner("<ul />");`
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Comment: This will result in <ul><div class="box"><li/><li/></div></ul>, won't it?

Comment: @phihag Yes It's true. SO I'll use wrapall with `.box li`